# Determine $f^{(5)}(0)$ without computing any derivatives?

Tags: calculus

Determine $f^{(5)}(0)$ without computing any derivatives? How do i approach a problem like this? I think i use maclaurin/taylor series but i'm not completely sure?

$f(x)=x\ln(1+x)$

$f(x)=x\cos x$

Comment: I think MacLaurin series is ok to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$f(x) = x \log{(1+x)} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1} \frac{x^{k+1}}{k}$$

For any sufficiently differentiable function

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k$$
so that

$$\frac{f^{(5)}(0)}{5!} = -\frac{1}{4} \implies f^{(5)}(0) = -30$$

Do a similar thing for

$$f(x) = x \cos{x} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k} \frac{x^{2 k+1}}{(2 k)!}$$

Comment: i don't understand where you get $\frac{-1}{5}$

Comment: @lawlipop: see above; I made an edit.

Comment: even so i don't understand how to calculate the value $\frac{-1}{4}$ what values/formula are you using to calculate it?

Comment: @lawlipop: see the expansion in the first equation above; it is the coefficient of $x^5$ in the expansion of $x \log{(1+x)}$.

Comment: oh i see, would that not result in calculating $f^{(4)}(0)$ ?

Comment: @lawlipop: No, because that would be the coefficient of $x^4$ in the expansion (times $4!$).

Answer (score 2):

When you have the taylor series 
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k$$ 
you know the $n$-th derivative is 
$$f^{(k)}(0)=a_k\cdot k! $$

Answer (score 2):

You can try and use [Leibniz's general product rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule):

$$ (fg)^{(n)} = \sum_{r = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{r} f^{(r)} g^{(n-r)}$$

where we use $h^{(m)}$ to denote the $m^{th}$ derivative of $h$.

If $f$ and $g$ have easy derivatives, you can compute the derivative of the product (your second problem).

If $fg$ and $g$ are functions whose derivatives are easily computed, this allows you to give you a recurrence of computing $f^{(k)}(0)$ in terms of $f^{(k-1)}(0), f^{(k-2)}(0)$ and so you don't really need to symbolically compute the whole derivatives of $f$.

This can be useful if you don't know the Taylor series before hand: you get an algorithm to compute it!

For example, consider the generating function for [Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number)

$$b(z) = \frac{z}{e^z - 1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} B_n \dfrac{z^n}{n!}$$

You can apply the above idea by applying the general product rule to $b(z)(e^z -1)$ to compute the coefficients $B_n$.

Comment: Here you surely complede derivatives

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: Please let me finish editing.

Comment: Isn't the usual notation of high order derivatives $f^{(n)}$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Yes, missed the brackets. Thanks! I might delete this answer anyway, though, perhaps it is not as useful for the specific problems OP has.

Comment: @Aryabhata no don't delete it, someone might be able to use it one day searching for the same question. thanks for your input but i was more set on using taylors series than, binomial series?(not sure which one you used) :)

Comment: @lawlipop: Ok, I have added an unrelated example to make the approach clearer.

Comment: Of course, you probably get similar recurrences by multiplying out the taylor series and solving the equations...